False-positive "Your post is mostly images."
I've tried to improve formatting and fixing a typo in this question: Adding more than one reviewer to a GitLab merge request
On save I got this error message:

Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.

That seems awkward, especially showing the error message after I've finished the edit.

The linked question is indeed mostly a screenshot. The error message is displayed after the screenshot is made inline which is when I would expect the error to happen and displayed.

@SecurityHound: Click "Edit"; Change "reuest" -> "request" in the text; Click "Save edits" - Error is only shown when I click "Save edits" without doing anything with the already existing image.  I agree that it's a short question but it seems a valid question and helpful (at least for me).

Oof, and not even a moderator can bypass it (well...not without being tricky; I'll write an answer with the workaround).

While the screenshot here isn't amazingly useful, it might clarify things slightly.  Either way, though, it's not the sort of content that the block is targeted at; the system allows the post to be submitted with the link simply removed and containing otherwise the same text.

This behavior seems like a suboptimal result of recent changes to block posts that are mostly images, similar to how posts with a code block and not much text are blocked (resulting in people often just posting the code as images instead, which is worse).  I'm not sure what the best solution is to fix this issue while still preserving the useful functionality of stopping people from writing mostly-image-of-code posts, but I've found a workaround for links (it doesn't work for inlined images, as noted in the comments).
Workaround for links to images
Obligatory preface: don't do this just to avoid the check if you're trying to post an image of code/errors/other text content that should be posted as text.  Please post it as text and just add some more explanation; your post will likely be closed if you use images to upload code for a question.
Edit the image link to replace https:// with // (that is, use a protocol-relative URL).  Since Stack Overflow pages are always served over HTTPS, these should be equivalent.
So, for the example linked in the question, this:
more than one [reviewer](https://i.sstatic.net/RZSq6.png)

becomes:
more than one [reviewer](//i.sstatic.net/RZSq6.png)


Side note: I'm documenting a way to bypass this check because I believe that anyone coming to Meta Stack Overflow to read documentation of the intricacies of the system is probably not going to be the sort of person who will ignore all the warnings about the problem with images of text, but instead will use it for the cases where an image really is just context.  If this workaround is being regularly abused to upload images that should really be text or otherwise create unsuitable posts that can only be posted using this trick, please put up a meta question with links to a few examples so that it can be evaluated whether this hole should be patched.

Why don't you just add a simple condition, like if the original content would not be saved then edits with the same "mostly images" error can be saved? This approach likely won't make things worse.

@palacsint Well, I'm not a Stack Exchange employee, so it's not my call.  That said, similar requests have been declined previously on the basis that it forces editors to make a more meaningful improvement to fix existing issues with the post (on the assumption that the filter is, at least in general, doing its job properly).  There's also some merit to subjecting all posts to the same rules; it helps catch cases like this where the rules are not really working as intended and get them reported.

This doesn't seem to work e.g. on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75352810/how-to-web-scrap-economic-calendar-data-from-tradingview-and-load-into-dataframe; I get "image links must start with https"

@tripleee Seems like it only works for links to images, rather than inlined images.

Doesn't seem to work for links to images anymore either. I tried the same format as your example and it still gave me that error that tripleee noticed.

Got All image URLs must start with https:// for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478637/differentiate-between-handwritten-and-machine-printed-texts
